# Datatable Add Column using JS

Tags: javascript, datatable

I am using https://datatables.net and I can add row after render `datatable` by using its built-in function table.row.add().draw()*. Problem is with Column. I want to add a column after render `datatable`. I can add column using `JS` but it is not making it sortable or workable until I don't refresh the page. Is there any way to solve this issue? I cannot able to find any solution over the search engine.

Comment: share us what you tried, no one will write code for you

Comment: table.row.add([column]).draw(false);
this is how I can add row.

============================

How can I add new column(s)?

Comment: I got a solution. Solution is to destroy instance and recreate. :) 
BTW thanks for your response :)